# Sending images through a socket using qt and read it using java

Tags: java, qt, sockets, image-processing

I'm trying to send an image upload in a Qt server trough the socket and visualize it in a client created using Java. Until now I have only transferred strings to communicate on both sides, and tried different examples for sending images but with no results.

The code I used to transfer the image in qt is:

```
QImage image;
image.load("../punton.png");
qDebug()<<"Image loaded";
QByteArray ban; // Construct a QByteArray object
QBuffer buffer(&ban);   // Construct a QBuffer object using the QbyteArray
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // Save the QImage data into the QBuffer
socket->write(ban);
```

In the other end the code to read in Java is:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(),1);
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\CLOUDMOTO\\Desktop\\JAVA\\image.png");
System.out.println("Receiving...");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
byte[] by = new byte[1];
for(int len; (len = in.read(by)) > 0;){
fout.write(by, 0, len);
System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

The process in Java gets stuck until I close the Qt server and after that the file generated is corrupt.

I'll appreciate any help because it's neccessary for me to do this and I'm new to programming with both languages.

Also I've used the following commands that and the receiving process now ends and show a message, but the file is corrupt.

```
socket->write(ban+"-1"); 
socket->close(); in qt.
```

And in java:

```
System.out.println(by); 
String received = new String(by, 0, by.length, "ISO8859_1");
System.out.println(received);
System.out.println("Done!");
```

[image]

Comment: Do you call `close` on the FileOutputStream after the loop?

Comment: Try flushing the socket's stream in the Qt server after writing the data.  Also, why is your buffer only 1 byte in size?

Comment: What size it should be it my image is of 1x1 pixels and the using the command image.size() is 105. Also I've tried the                     socket->write(ban);                                                 socket->flush();
socket->waitForBytesWritten(10000);                               Also I already tried with different byte size and the process always stucks in the loop in java.

Comment: also ive tried to close the FileOutputStream after the loop

Comment: try buffer.flush(); before socket->write().

Comment: Use HTTP for transferring files, not sockets.

Comment: @artbristol Uh, and HTTP is supposed to be transported over what?

Comment: @PavelZdenek TCP sockets, obviously. But a decent HTTP library sorts out request length, content type, chunking, etc.

Comment: @artbristol Ok then :) The issue is that OP would have to integrate HTTP server library and implement request handler in his receiver, when he apparently has problem with recognizing the need for request length alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot transport file over socket in such simple way. You are not giving the receiver any clue, what number of bytes is coming. Read javadoc for [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) carefully. Your receiver is in endless loop because it is waiting for next byte until the stream is closed. So you have partially fixed that by calling `socket->close()` at the sender side. Ideally, you need to write the length of `ban` into the socket before the buffer, read that length at receiver side and then receive only that amount of bytes. Also `flush` and `close` the receiver stream before trying to read the received file.

I have absolutely no idea what you wanted to achieve with `socket->write(ban+"-1")`. Your logged output starts with `%PNG` which is correct. I can see there `"-1"` at the end, which means that you added characters to the image binary file, hence you corrupted it. Why so?

And no, 1x1 PNG does not have size of 1 byte. It does not have even 4 bytes (red,green,blue,alpha). PNG needs some things like header and control checksum. Have a look at the size of the file on filesystem. This is your required `by` size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helps me a lot, i notice that the file dont open because of the ini string at the beginnig and since i used that string to send a command i solve the problem adding a in.skip(bytes) so  in the final file the string dont appear.